Tailwinds padding does not work after reload page
So i'm using tailwinds with nextjs 14 and i encountered this situation.
i set pl-[15rem] in my layout, sidebar has width = 15rem. My target is pushing the page content to the right side and sidebar on the left side. It works at the first load but after i reload, the page content overlaps sidebar. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
Here is my code:
Layout.tsx
<html lang="en">
  <body
    className={`antialiased relative pl-[15rem]`}
  >
    <Sidebar />
    {children}
  </body>
</html>

sidebar.tsx
<div className='w-[15rem] h-dvh shadow-md absolute top-0 left-0 z-10'>
  <ul className='p-2'>
    {
      menus.map((menu) => (
        <Link href={menu.link} key={menu.title}>
          <li className='p-2 font-semibold rounded-sm hover:bg-slate-200'>{menu.title}</li>
        </Link>
      ))
    }
  </ul>
</div>

page.tsx
<div className='p-3 relative'>
  <h1 className='font-bold text-2xl mb-3'>Dashboard</h1>
  <Table
    aria-label="Example table with dynamic content"
    className='mb-3'>
    <TableHeader>
      {
        columns.map((column) => (
          <TableColumn key={column.key}>{column.label}</TableColumn>
        ))
      }
    </TableHeader>
    <TableBody items={rows}>
      {
        rows.map((item) => (
          <TableRow key={item.key}>
            <TableCell>{item.name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{item.sales}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{item.income}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))
      }
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
  <Pagination
    total={10}
    initialPage={1}
    // className='float-right'
    onChange={handlePageChange} />
</div>

the page content overlaps sidebar content
am i setting folders correctly?
here is my folder structure

Have you inspected the elements in your browser to see whether they have the styles you expect? If they do, then it's not Tailwind's generation at fault.

i just realize that it only receives className from root layout but it receives  in my (client) layout

Your problem is most likely your sidebar having an absolute rather then fixed position, this removes it from the normal box model/ web flow.changing the container into a flex to make it appear side by side on opposite ends and changing it from absolute to fixed or block may help your problem.
